# Excel is it possible to create a master file template, that updates other worksheets automatically

Tags: excel, userform, excel-2016

I’m creating an excel user form app for a department that is located in 2 different places.
What I don’t know is: is it possible to have a master file (like Wordpress multi site) where I can add updates, make modifications etc… and the workbooks with userform that departments are using gets updated automatically (without me moving to locations physically and adding the updates one by one) ?
My company users Excel 2016.
Thanks for any replies and suggestions :)

Comment: Make one the master and have the other call the latest info from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a macro to updates other files and set it run on some event with master macro - for example on event Workbook_SheetTableUpdate